# Separating a string in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

We have a field in our table as `LastName,FirstName(FromSomewhere)` and I need to separate the string into
`lastNAme firstname` and ignore the `(FromSomewhere)` with a select statement. Any help is really appreciated.

I tried with

```
Select substring(
         LEFT(_Owner, charindex('(', _Owner) - 1), 
             charindex(',', _Owner) + 1, len(LEFT(_Owner, cha‌​rindex('(', _Owner) - 1))) 
from CC;
```

is what i have tried and i get an error as

> Msg 536, Level 16, State 5, Line 1 Invalid length parameter passed to the SUBSTRING function.

Comment: What have your tried?. Where are you stuck? What error are you getting?

Comment: sql and sql server are not the same thing

Comment: Sorry about the confusion, it is sql server

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are on sql-server 2005 or above:

**[Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/84cc2/1)**

```
;with cte as (
   select _Owner, charindex(',',_Owner) first, charindex('(',_Owner) second 
   from CC
)
select left(_Owner,first-1) lastName,
       substring(_Owner, first+1, second - (first+1)) firstName
from cte
```

Answer (score 0):

Read [on Substring](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187748.aspx)

> length
>
> Is a positive integer or bigint expression that specifies how many
>   characters of the expression will be returned. If length is negative,
>   an error is generated and the statement is terminated. If the sum of
>   start and length is greater than the number of characters in
>   expression, the whole value expression beginning at start is returned.

Answer (score 0):

So long as you're only doing this once (to split the data into separate columns for FirstName, LastName) then you could do it like so. Performance would be horrible if you wanted to use the following technique in a regular query though.

```
declare @myString nvarchar(200) = 'LastName,FirstName(FromSomewhere)'

select  SUBSTRING(@myString, 1, CHARINDEX(',', @myString, 1) - 1),
        SUBSTRING(@myString, CHARINDEX(',', @myString, 1) + 1, CHARINDEX('(', @myString, 1) - CHARINDEX(',', @myString, 1) - 1)
```

Comment: Still receive the same error with the code above,as Msg 536, Level 16, State 5, Line 1
Invalid length parameter passed to the SUBSTRING function. It does return two rows one as null null and the first record and nothing else